# No menu in TeXstudio

Tags: gnome, menu, text-editor

I wonder why I don't see the menu on the top of the page (File Edit ... Help). I have just updated it from 2.9.4 to 2.10.2. Is there something I can do to make the menu appear?
As a non computer expert, I have already tried to

- move the mouse everywhere,
- Clic right and look for some option to activate/desactivate,
- Restart the computer.

[image]

It runs on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / GNOME Flashback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been answer by [Tim Hoffmann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24770/tim-hoffmann) on [http://tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273996/no-menu-in-texstudio/274096#274096):

> This is a known issue with Qt 5. See http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1512/